# A3 landscape paper inside A4 report

Tags: pdf, geometry, landscape

I'm trying to find a way to incorporate an A3 landscape page in my report. I found a way using `\newgeometry`, but the problem here is, I can't get it to return to my preamble settings after using it. I wondered if there were another way to do it. It should be just like a normal side in the document, with headers, page numbers and everything, but on an A3 landscape page.

Comment: `\newgeometry{...} ...your A3 landscape page ... \restoregeometry` ?

Comment: You can also simply overlay the margins using negative \hspace.

Comment: The `geometry` documentation says: `\newgeometry` is almost similar to `\geometry` except that `\newgeometry` disables all the options specified in the preamble and skips the papersize-related options: landscape, portrait and paper size options (such as papersize, paper=a4paper and so forth).